# Multiple group by does not give the output as expected for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following documents in a collection . As part of the aggregation pipeline this is the input I have at a particular stage.
I am using the group by operator in the next stage so that I can get the desired output

```
[
  {
    "Id": "Id1",
    "Title": "Title1",
    "User": {
      "Id": "Userid1",
      "Title": "User Title1",
      "Concerts": {
        "Id": "Concert3",
        "Title": "Concert title3",
        "Users": {
          "Id": "Userid1",
          "Title": "User Title Concert3"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": "Id1",
    "Title": "Title1",
    "User": {
      "Id": "Userid2",
      "Title": "User Title2",
      "Concerts": {
        "Id": "Concert1",
        "Title": "Concert title1",
        "Users": {
          "Id": "Userid2",
          "Title": "User Title2 Concert1"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": "Id1",
    "Title": "Title1",
    "User": {
      "Id": "Userid2",
      "Title": "User Title1",
      "Concerts": {
        "Id": "Concert4",
        "Title": "Concert title1",
        "Users": {
          "Id": "Userid2",
          "Title": "User Title2 Concert4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to do group by so that the final output is

```
{
    "Id": "Id1",
    "Title": "Title1",
    "User": [
        {
            "Id": "Userid2",
            "Title": "User Title1",
            "Concerts": [
                {
                    "Id": "Concert4",
                    "Title": "Concert title1",
                    "Users": {
                        "Id": "Userid2",
                        "Title": "User Title2 Concert4"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Id": "Concert1",
                    "Title": "Concert title1",
                    "Users": {
                        "Id": "Userid2",
                        "Title": "User Title2 Concert1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": "Userid1",
            "Title": "User Title1",
            "Concerts": [
                {
                    "Id": "Concert1",
                    "Title": "Concert title1",
                    "Users": {
                        "Id": "Userid1",
                        "Title": "User Title Concert1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Id": "Concert2",
                    "Title": "Concert title1",
                    "Users": {
                        "Id": "Userid1",
                        "Title": "User Title Concert2"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Id": "Concert3",
                    "Title": "Concert title1",
                    "Users": {
                        "Id": "Userid1",
                        "Title": "User Title Concert3"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So far I have tried these and I am not able to get them in a single document

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "id": "$_id",
        "userId": "$User.Id",
        "ConcertsId": "$User.Concerts.Id"
      },
      Title: {
        $first: "$Title"
      },
      User: {
        $addToSet: "$User"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "id": "$_id",
        "userId": "$User.Id",
        "ConcertsId": "$User.Concerts.Id",
        "InnerUserId": "$User.Concerts.User.Id"
      },
      Title: {
        $first: "$Title"
      },
      User: {
        $addToSet: "$User"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Is `groupby` the correct option to get the data in the aggregation pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `$group` by with correct attributes. `_id` and `Id` are not the same, since `Id` is your business object, and `_id` internal MongoDB field.

#### Steps

1. Group `Concerts`
2. Group `User`
3. Shape desired object (`$project`) and remove residual fields (`_id:0`).

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "Id": "$Id",
        "Title": "$Title",
        "UserId": "$User.Id",
        "UserTitle": "$User.Title"
      },
      Concerts: {
        $push: "$User.Concerts"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "Id": "$_id.Id",
        "Title": "$_id.Title"
      },
      User: {
        $push: {
          "Id": "$_id.UserId",
          "Title": "$_id.UserTitle",
          "Concerts": "$Concerts"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "Id": "$_id.Id",
      "Title": "$_id.Title",
      "User": "$User"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4YwBKReQiyo)